# index.jsp not working, just shows source code on browser

Tags: java, spring, jsp, model-view-controller

In a Spring MVC application, I'm trying to pass a list to a JSP page and show it on a table, but my *index.jsp* isn't rendered well and just shows source code on browser.

Here is my controller:

```
package com.orantaj.controllers;

import com.orantaj.service.EventService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@RestController
public class IndexController {

    @Autowired
    EventService eventService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public void setEvents(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        try {
            request.setAttribute("basketballEvents", eventService.getBasketballEvents());
            request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is JSP:

```
<%@ page import="com.orantaj.model.BasketballEvent" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<table>     
    <tr>     
        <th>Maç Kodu</th>
        <th>Lig</th>
        <th>Maç Saati</th>
        <th>Takımlar</th>
    </tr>
              
    <%List<BasketballEvent> basketballEvents = (List<BasketballEvent>) request.getAttribute("basketballEvents");%>
         <%if (basketballEvents != null && basketballEvents.size() > 0) {%>
              
    <%for (BasketballEvent event : basketballEvents) {%>          

    <tr>     
        <td><%=event.getMatchCode()%></td>
        <td><%=event.getLeague()%></td>
        <td><%=event.getMatchDate()%></td>
        <td><%=event.getHomeTeam() + " " + event.getAwayTeam()%></td>
    </tr>
                <%
            }
        }
    %>     
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: what server are you using?

Comment: why do you use @RestController to dispay a .jsp?

Comment: solved ;

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31231354/el-expression-not-evaluated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to annotate your controller class with `@Controller` instead of using the `@RestController` annotation which implies that all request handling method assumes the `@ResponseBody` semantics, which (from Javadoc):

> indicates a method return value should be bound to the web response body.

You can check the annotation inernals:

- [`@RestController`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html)
- [`@ResponseBody`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseBody.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have always used the view resolver in spring bean instead of passing jsp name with extension in controller. You need the pass the jsp name without extension in this case just index and the view resolver will resolve it. It works fine. I believe this is the issue.

```
     <bean id="viewResolver"
           class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
           <property name="prefix">
              <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
           </property>
           <property name="suffix">
              <value>.jsp</value>
           </property>
     </bean>

</beans>
```

Also you should use just `@Controller` annotation instead of `@RestController` if you dont have specfic requirement

Comment: thanks a lot :) About @RestController, it was habit but now i know right one thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to avoid this problem :

- You have to use @Controller instead of @Restcontroller and add the bean InternalResourceViewResolver as said above to define the suffix and prefix of your pages.

See an example here : http://www.breathejava.com/spring-restful-web-service-tutorial-with-json-format-java-configuration/

- Or, Develop in the client side an ajax request to consume your default web service. I prefer that you use AngularJS Framework.

Comment: i know angular is the best option but my time is limited, so first i need to learn angular etc. Thanks for both two advices, first is good for me now :)

Comment: This is a pure server side issue, and switching client library won't fix that!