# JSP on Tomcat is displaying as source, not processed as JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tomcat, websphere

Note: this is NOT a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29182591/index-jsp-not-working-just-shows-source-code-on-browser). The question pointed too was using a @RestController, and their problem was solved by switching to @Controller. I am using a @Controller and org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver

Porting a web app from WebSphere to Tomcat. The following is in my mvc-config.xml file:

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="redirect:/dashboard"/>
<mvc:view-controller path="/login" view-name="login"/>

<mvc:view-controller path="/**.html" view-name="login"/>

<!-- Resolves view names to protected .jsp resources within the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

When I launch the app from Tomcat, I get the following test displayed (which is the text of /WEB-INF/views/login.jsp, so that part is working):

```
<%@page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<html>
<head>  
    <title>Please log in</title>
    <style>
        h1{
            font-size:1.5em;            
        }

        h2{
            font-size:1.1em;
        }

        label, input{
            font-size:1.5em;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery("#j_username").focus();
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <h1>Welcome to Our App</h1>

    <c:if test="${not empty param.login_error}">
      <div class='error' style="color: red;">
        Your login attempt was not successful, try again.
      </div>
      <div>
        If you need access to Our App, please contact your supervisor and they can get you access.
      </div>
    </c:if>

    <h2>Please login to continue.</h2>
    ...
```

IOW, the complete contents of login.jsp are being displayed, without any processing of any sort being done.  Happens in both Firefox and Chrome, Tomcat 7.0.61.  This is what shows up in my Tomcat log files:

```
2821136 [http-8080-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - /dashboard at position 1 of 6 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2821136 [http-8080-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository  - No HttpSession currently exists
2821136 [http-8080-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository  - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
2821136 [http-8080-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - /dashboard at position 2 of 6 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2821136 [http-8080-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - /dashboard at position 3 of 6 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2821136 [http-8080-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - /dashboard at position 4 of 6 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AuthenticationFilter'
2821136 [http-8080-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - /dashboard at position 5 of 6 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2821137 [http-8080-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2821137 [http-8080-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - /dashboard at position 6 of 6 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2821137 [http-8080-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  - Checking match of request : '/dashboard'; against '/secure/super/**'
2821137 [http-8080-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor  - Public object - authentication not attempted
2821137 [http-8080-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - /dashboard reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2821137 [http-8080-4] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - DispatcherServlet with name 'Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet' processing GET request for [/cemWar/dashboard]
2821137 [http-8080-4] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping  - Mapping [/dashboard] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [edu.mayo.lpea.lsa.cem.controllers.DashboardController@4e939c89] and 1 interceptor
2821137 [http-8080-4] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Last-Modified value for [/cemWar/dashboard] is: -1
2821137 [http-8080-4] DEBUG org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker  - Invoking request handler method: public java.lang.String edu.mayo.lpea.lsa.cem.controllers.DashboardController.loadDashboard(javax.servlet.http.HttpSession,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap,edu.mayo.lpea.lsa.cem.config.UserDetails)
2821137 [http-8080-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor  - Secure object: ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public java.lang.String edu.mayo.lpea.lsa.cem.controllers.DashboardController.loadDashboard(javax.servlet.http.HttpSession,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap,edu.mayo.lpea.lsa.cem.config.UserDetails); target is of class [edu.mayo.lpea.lsa.cem.controllers.DashboardController]; Attributes: [ROLE_READER]
2821137 [http-8080-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor  - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2821137 [http-8080-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased  - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter@91e1a75, returned: -1
2821137 [http-8080-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased  - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter@175afc00, returned: 0
2821138 [http-8080-4] WARN  org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource  - ResourceBundle [/WEB-INF/messages/messages] not found for MessageSource: Can't find bundle for base name /WEB-INF/messages/messages, locale en_US
2821138 [http-8080-4] WARN  org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource  - ResourceBundle [/WEB-INF/messages/messages] not found for MessageSource: Can't find bundle for base name /WEB-INF/messages/messages, locale en_US
2821138 [http-8080-4] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Could not complete request
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:60)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
    at edu.mayo.lpea.lsa.cem.controllers.DashboardController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$27934b39_2.loadDashboard(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:434)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2821139 [http-8080-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter  - Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:60)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
    at edu.mayo.lpea.lsa.cem.controllers.DashboardController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$27934b39_2.loadDashboard(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:434)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2821139 [http-8080-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache  - DefaultSavedRequest added to Session: DefaultSavedRequest[http://127.0.0.1:8080/cemWar/dashboard]
2821139 [http-8080-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter  - Calling Authentication entry point.
2821139 [http-8080-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy  - Redirecting to 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/cemWar/login'
2821139 [http-8080-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository  - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2821139 [http-8080-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter  - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

What do I have set up wrong here?  I am a complete JSP noob.  Note: none of my Controllers are "@RestController they are all @Controller

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that WebSphere includes jstl, and Tomcat doesn't.  The Maven POM had jstl as "provided".  Eliminating that fixed the problem.