# EL expression not evaluated

Tags: jsp, servlets, el

Here is my test servlet ;

```
public class EventListServlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        process(request, response);
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        process(request, response);
    }

    private void process(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        request.setAttribute("name", "test1");
        request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

and test jsp ;

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
<p>${name}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

and the output is **${name}**

it should write test1 :/ what's wrong with that ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Earlier versions of JSP disable EL by default.  See: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/819-3669/bnajh/index.html

To enable EL evaluation on this page, try putting the following directive at the top of your JSP file:

```
<%@page isELIgnored="false" %>
```

Comment: i just added but now result is just ; Hello World!

Comment: Are you 100% certain that your servlet code is being executed?

Comment: Can you try this just as a test: Just before the "html': tag in you jsp, put the following line: **<%request.setAttribute("name", "foobar");%>**    That will tell you if the problem is with EL or if it is with the setting of the attribute.

Comment: i did it now result is Hello World! foobar it works.

Comment: i'm sure about that, i put breakpoint at debugger, it pass on servlet

Comment: try changing **.forward()** to **.include()**.  It wonder if the forward is creating a new request context.

Comment: By the way, i use tomcat as a container. Could it depends on it ?

Comment: I doubt it.  The behavior is defined by the jSP specification.  Something this basic will not vary from container to container.